# Get value of custom user field in Drupal 7 template?

Tags: php, drupal, user-interface, drupal-7, custom-fields

I'm building my first site with drupal. And I made a custom user field: Full name.
Now I want to get the value of this fild in my template to say “Hello, %username%”.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on your setup/field name, something like this in `template.php` (preprocess function for the template file):

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page() {
  global $user;
  $user = user_load($user->uid); // Make sure the user object is fully loaded

  $vars['full_name'] = $user->field_full_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
}
```

Then something like this in `page.tpl.php`:

```
if (isset($full_name) && !empty($full_name)) :
  echo 'Hello ' . $full_name;
endif;
```

Note that `LANGUAGE_NONE` may need to be changed if you're running a multi-lingual site.

Comment: You should use field_get_items. Direct access can break on multi-language website or if the field structure change.

Comment: @gagarine This was a long, long time ago. Field structures can't change FYI, there's no mechanism for it.

Comment: Does this work only in templates, or also in a module? when I load my user with `$account = user_load($uid);`, I only get empty arrays instead of the custom fields: `$account->pwyw_balance` is just an array() without content. Do custom fields need to be loaded with extra code? Same thing happens when I load the user using `$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $account)->value()`. `$wrapper['pwyw_balance']`is an empty array.

Answer (score 19):

Clive's answer is correct except that you should use [`field_get_items`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/function/field_get_items/7) to get the values for a field. It will handle the language for you. You should also sanitize the value.

```
function THEME_preprocess_page() {
  global $user;
  $user = user_load($user->uid); // Make sure the user object is fully loaded
  $full_names = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_full_name');
  if ($full_names) {
    $vars['full_name'] = check_plain($full_names[0]['value']);
  }
}
```

If your site uses the [Entity API](http://drupal.org/project/entity) module, you can also use a entity metadata wrapper like this

```
function THEME_preprocess_page() {
  global $user;
  $user = user_load($user->uid); // Make sure the user object is fully loaded
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
  $vars['full_name'] = $wrapper->field_full_name->get(0)->value(array('sanitize' => TRUE));
}
```

See also [Writing robust code that uses fields, in Drupal 7](http://pixeljets.com/blog/writing-robust-code-uses-fields-drupal-7)

Comment: missing `$` sign in the `entity_metadata_wrapper()` call should be `$user` instead of `user`

Comment: Hi Pierre, following code is not get any data.  $user = user_load('72'); $first_name = field_get_items('user', $user, 'field_first_name');

Comment: If you don't get any data it means there is no value for the field on that entity.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked quite a while ago, but I wanted to post an alternative. It looks like you want to change the field in the $variables array that is `$variables['name']` to what you have in your custom field that I've called `field_real_name`. If you are using a preprocess function, there is no need to pull in the global `$user` object. You have access to the `$variables` array, so you can get the user information with this - it will load the information associated with the uid ([see template_preprocess_username](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_username/7)):

```
function mythemename_preprocess_username(&$variables) {
    $account = user_load($variables['account']->uid);
    ...more code will go here in a moment
}
```

If you `dpm($account)` (or `kpr($account)` if you aren't using devel) you will see that you have access to all of the user information, without using the global `$user` object.

Then you can change the output of `$variables['name']` to be your `field_real_name` as follows:

```
function mythemename_preprocess_username(&$variables) {

  // Load user information with user fields
  $account = user_load($variables['account']->uid);

  // See if user has real_name set, if so use that as the name instead
  $real_name = $account->field_real_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['safe_value'];
  if (isset($real_name)) {
    $variables['name'] = $real_name;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can add the below code anywhere in the template file.

```
<?php
global $user;
$user = user_load($user->uid);
print $user->name;
?>
```